# Using OR relation in meta_query to check for a value before sorting by another

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, query, meta-query

I am writing a pair of queries for a site with an events listing function. Events can be either on a single date or over several (multi-day). All events have a value in custom field `event_date`. Multi-day events also have an `end_date` value.

Single day events should be in the 'upcoming events' list (first query) until the end of their `event_date`, and multi-day events should stay until the end of their `end_date`. Once they are no longer in the upcoming list they should move to the 'past events' list (new query, same page).

The upcoming query works perfectly. Multi-day events stay in the list between their `event_date` and `end_date` values:

```php
$now     = date('Ymd', strtotime("now"));
$future  = date('Ymd', strtotime("+24 months"));
$uc_args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'event',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        // check post has end_date and it is between $now and $future
        array(
            'key'     => 'end_date',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            'value'   => array($now, $future),
        ),
        // if no end date check event_date is between $now and $future
        array(
            'key'     => 'event_date',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            'value'   => array($now, $future),
        ),
    ),
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'orderby'  => 'meta_value',
    'order'    => 'ASC',
    'nopaging' => true,
);
```

The past query is constructed exactly the same way, but multi-day events are appearing once their `event–date` has passed, even if they have an `end_date` value:

```php
$past    = date('Ymd', strtotime("-999 months"));
$now     = date('Ymd', strtotime("now"));
$uc_args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'event',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'  => 'OR',
        // check post has end_date and it is between $past and $now
        array(
            'key'     => 'end_date',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            'value'   => array($past, $now),
        ),
        // if no end date check event_date is between $past and $now
        array(
            'key'     => 'event_date',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            'value'   => array($past, $now),
        ),
    ),
    'meta_key'       => 'event_date',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'nopaging'       => false,
    'posts_per_page' => '8',
);
```

I can see how an OR relation would include all posts which meet either criteria, but it doesn't do this in the first query. So far as I know there is no ELSE relation but that is the idea I am aiming for here.

Why does this work for upcoming events but not for past events?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be part of the problem in your past query (the second one)

```php
        array(
            'key'     => 'end_date',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            'value'   => array($past, $now),
        ),
```

You're using `BETWEEN` but I think something like `<` would be what you want. You don't want to show events that have ended between `$past` and `$now`, right? You want to show events that have ended in general.

```php
        array(
            'key'     => 'end_date',
            'compare' => '<',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            'value'   => $now,
        ),
```

Comment: You're not wrong, but in fact I've tried this both ways (the `BETWEEN` relation is left from an attempt to try all I could think of, and was a `<` just on `$now` previously. I'll probably put it back in the final version). The behaviour is unchanged by this though, and your version still shows past events that have started but not finished.